# Angular in docker with lerna not building

Tags: angular, docker, lerna

I'm trying to deploy a single Angular client from my lerna monorepo via docker.

For this I created the following Docker file.

```
# Build environment
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as build

# Work dir
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Set env values
ENV LOG_LEVEL=debug
ENV NODE_ENV=production

# Add lerna
COPY package.json .
COPY lerna.json .
RUN npm i lerna @angular/cli -g --loglevel notice

# Copy packages
COPY packages/client ./packages/client

# bootstrap
RUN yarn install --production --no-optional
RUN lerna bootstrap --scope=@proj/client -- --production --no-optional

# build
RUN lerna run build:prod --scope=@proj/client

# Run environment
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
COPY --from=build ./packages/client/dist/client /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build ./packages/client/.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

But when running `docker build -t test -f packages/client/Dockerfile .` it gives me following error:

```
lerna notice cli v3.22.1
lerna notice filter including "@proj/client"
lerna info filter [ '@proj/client' ]
lerna info Executing command in 1 package: "yarn run build:prod"
lerna ERR! yarn run build:prod exited 127 in '@proj/client'
lerna ERR! yarn run build:prod stdout:
yarn run v1.15.2
$ ng build --prod
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

lerna ERR! yarn run build:prod stderr:
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build-impl.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
See "/tmp/ng-OFgChe/angular-errors.log" for further details.
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

I've tried several combinations of the #bootstrap block:

- I've tried with and without the `yarn install`
- I've tried removing the `--production` and `--no-optional` flags
- I've tried moving the `devDependencies` to the root `package.json`

Running these commands local (on a cleaned working folder) works perfectly, but each one of them gives me the same result in my docker build. So it's not that the `@angular-devkit` isn't listed as dependecy

Anybody got any clue on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to resolve it.
Apparently with or without the `--production` didn't matter for [yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-production-true-false)

changing it to `--production=false` or changing the `NODE_ENV` to something else fixes the issue